# Is this question solvable using the law of sines and cosines?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, plane-geometry

1. Is it possible to (analytically) calculate the area of the following triangle using the [rules of sines and cosines](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cosine2.shtml)?
2. Is it possible to calculate it using only the rule of sines?

The data given is:
$BD$ is a median to $AC$, $\angle ABD = 50^\circ$, $\angle DBC = 18^\circ$ and $BD = 4.2~\text{cm}$.

It seems to me that some data is missing.

Am I right?
[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like anything is missing. I had to solve an equation numerically but I got BDC=about $138^\circ$ and then you can fill everything in from there. The median information was critical since that allows you to decouple the angles from the unknown lengths $AD$ and $DC$.

Comment: This is for high-school students who cant solve numerical equations. The meaning is to give an analytical solution

Comment: There is no need in numerical solution here, answer can be given as analytical expression containing input data. You didn't show that BD is median in picture, so I firstly decided that some information is missing. Now I see that information is enough to recover all sides and find area. Let $\angle ABD=\alpha$, $\angle CBD=\beta$, $BD=a$, $\angle BDA=\gamma$ (unknown), $AD=CD=b$ (unknown). Then use sine rule in $ABD$ and $CBD$. Then solve for $\gamma$ and $b$. Then $S=ab\sin\gamma$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Can you write out how you get $\gamma$ without numerics? I don't see how to do it, since you end up with an equation involving two sinusoids with disparate phases and you can't write it as $\sin(\dots)=\sin(\dots)$. Specifically I had $x=BDC$ and then $\frac{\sin(162^\circ-x)}{\sin(x-50^\circ)}=\frac{\sin(18^\circ)}{\sin(50^\circ)}$. I could see there being a shortcut to get specifically the area analytically however; I missed that this was what the question was asking for at first.

Comment: One can solve this as trigonometrical equation. $\sin(162^\circ-x)\sin(50^\circ)=A\sin x+B\cos x$, the same for $\sin(x-50^\circ)\sin(18^\circ)$. Then divide by $\cos x$ and you can find $\tan x$. But solution of L.F. given in answer is much simpler.

Comment: I see your point, that works (although the work the computer will do to give a decimal result is more or less the same anyway).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: extend $BD$ to $E$, such that $DE = BD$.  You should be able to find enough information in the triangle $\triangle BCE$ to calculate its area.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = AB$ , $ y = BC$, $\beta = \angle BDA $

Then

$\text{Area} = \dfrac{1}{2} (4.2) ( x \sin(50^\circ) + y \sin (18^\circ) ) = \dfrac{1}{2} x y \sin(68^\circ)\hspace{15pt} (1) $

And from the law of sines we have

$\dfrac{ x }{\sin \beta } = \dfrac{AD}{\sin(50^\circ)}$

$\dfrac{y}{\sin \beta } = \dfrac{DC}{\sin(18)^\circ}$

So by dividing these two equations we get

$ \dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{ \sin(18^\circ)}{ \sin(50^\circ) } \hspace{15pt} (2)$

Equation $(2)$ implies that

$ y = \left(\dfrac{ \sin(50^\circ)}{ \sin(18^\circ) } \right) x \hspace{15pt} (3)$

Substituting for $y$ from $(3)$ into $(1)$, and dividing by $x$ (because $x$ cannot be zero), results in

$ (4.2) ( 2 \sin(50^\circ) ) = x \dfrac{\sin(68^\circ) \sin(50^\circ) }{\sin(18^\circ)} $

Hence,

$ x = \dfrac{ 8.4 \sin(18^\circ) }{\sin(68^\circ)} $

and, consequently,

$ y = \dfrac{ 8.4 \sin(50^\circ) }{ \sin(68^\circ)}$

And finally, the area is

$\text{Area} = \dfrac{1}{2} x y \sin(68^\circ) = 35.28 \dfrac{ \sin(18^\circ) \sin(50^\circ) }{ \sin(68^\circ)} \approx 9.0074$